# How to call an external file to display ad on iOS app?

Tags: ios, url, external

I am working on iOS apps and want to call an interstitial ad based on an external file.  Here is exactly what I want to do. I feel like it should be simple, but with my limited experience, I cannot figure it out.

The code to call a Revmob Interstitial is:

```
[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
```

What I want to do is put it in an external file, lets call it interstitial.php.

Instead of placing the exact code for the interstitial in the app, I want to call the external file. Something like this:

```
call file src=interstitial.php
```

The goal is to be able to change to other ads remotely. For example, if I wanted to show a Chartboost ad, I simply change the external interstitial.php file to:

```
[cb showInterstitial];
```

To make things easy, I would just load both SDK's and basic app information, but I could incorporate all of that into the external file if I wanted to.

Comment: How are you imagining that the data returned by the PHP page would work? Is it returning a flag to tell the app which SDK to use?

Comment: I just need to pull in the command.  I have seen tutorials on doing this for data to populate a table, but there is 100 lines of code to do that.  I literally just want to pull in a line or two of code.  For revmob and chartboost, I literally just need to pull in a single line of code

Answer (score 0):

On iOS all applications are sandboxed and you will not have access rights to the file not in your bundle or your documents. Files in your documents is accessible for your application only.
Best solution on my opinion is to place webpage somewhere in the web and get your content from   internet

Comment: You are right.  The file would be a webpage, but I just need to know how to pull in the data.

Comment: You can post xml and parse it for example or put some kind a comma separated list

Comment: levgenii, can you give me an example of how to do this?  I am new to this programming language.  From previous experience, it seems like this should be simple, but I just don't know how to do it.